# Convert from ASP.NET membership to the new ASP.NET Identity API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm considering converting my existing MVC 4 which is currently using ASP.NET membership for authentication and authorization to the new ASP.NET Identity model now available in MVC 5 and the like recently released with VS 2013.  Aside from upgrading to MVC 5, does anyone have thoughts on what would be needed to convert the application to this new framework with the least impact on existing users?

Ideally I'd like to preserve their password hashes and salts to keep from forcing users to change their password after the conversion.  Also, there has been talk of implementing Federation as an alternate login for some clients so I'd need to use the claims capabilities in the new system too.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are basically two basic ways to migrate the user accounts:

- all at once: for this to work, the hashing algorithm "configuration" needs to be identical on both systems (if "one-way hashing" is used, and it usually is) because there's no way for you to know the users' passwords during this kind of migration. All you can do is just copy the data from A to B.
- "rolling": move the accounts one at a time, more specifically, during the logon phase, when you happen to know the user's password, so you can do pretty much anything with it (like creating a new hash and store it somewhere else). But, the downside is that you need to keep both old and new authentication system up and running for an extended period of time (depending how long it's gonna take for all of your users to log in).

If your MVC 4 project uses the default "simple membership" provider, the good news is that the hashing algorithm used is the same. Simple membership is open source, here's the crypto code:

https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs

The new identity system is, unfortunately, not open-sourced, but it turns out it uses the same algorithm (yay!) -- just copy a password hash and it'll work (don't worry about salt -- it's included in the hash "blob")!!! **So, "bulk" migration is definitely possible.**

However, I strongly suggest that you don't do this yet. The new identity system seems to be in flux, so maybe waiting a couple of weeks is a good idea at the moment. For example, the source code may become available (so I could finally see how the "SecurityStamp" value works and what's it for :)

OTOH, if you are using the old, "pre-simple membership" (pre-MVC4) authentication, it utilizes a completely different hashing algorithm (SHA256, IIRC), so there's no quick way to migrate -- you'll have to wait for all your users to log in to move their account to the new system. (Of course, you could accelerate the process by sending them an informative email about why they should do it asap :)

I hope this helps.

Wrt Federation -- I have no idea :)

Comment: We just had the same situation, and we resolved it by copying the old users to the new DB, giving them all a fixed password (a couple of random GUIDs copied together) and when we validate a log-in, we check if the user's current password is that long GUID. If it is, we provide him/her with a message and the "retrieve your password"-screen, where they can input their username, which sends an email, in which they can change their password via a url. Hope this helps!